# How to get an element height after componentDidUpdate?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to build a dynamic height grid where I have in a fixed height (100vh) as many rows as I can, without overflowing, Each row has a variable height, so I cannot calculate the number of rows that is going to fit in advance.

Here is the code I'm working on as a prototype:

```
.rows-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
 }

.rows-inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: orange;
}


import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import "./styles.css";

const data = Array.apply(null, { length: 500 }).map((value, index) => {
  return {
    data: "Row #" + index
  };
});

class DynamicGrid extends Component {
  state = {
    viewRowsStartIndex: 0,
    viewRows: 1,
    viewAddRows: true
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.renderLines();
  };

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.renderLines();
  };

  renderLines = () => {
    let { viewAddRows, viewRows } = this.state;

    let containerHeight = this.refs.container.offsetHeight;
    let innerContainerHeight = this.refs.innerContainer.offsetHeight;

    console.log("HEIGHTS:");
    console.log(
      "CONTAINER: " +
        containerHeight +
        " INNER CONTAINER: " +
        innerContainerHeight
    );
    console.log("STATE:");
    console.log(
      "viewRows: " + viewRows + " - viewAddRows: " + this.state.viewAddRows
    );

    if (viewAddRows === true && innerContainerHeight < containerHeight) {
      this.setState({
        viewRows: viewRows + 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        viewAddRows: false,
        viewRows: viewRows - 1
      });
    }
  };

  getRow = (row, index) => {
    let height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 10;
    return (
      <div key={index} style={{ height: height }}>
        {row.data}
      </div>
    );
  };

  getRows = rows => {
    let { viewRowsStartIndex, viewRows } = this.state;

    let ret = [];

    let rowIndex = 0;
    for (
      let index = viewRowsStartIndex;
      index < viewRowsStartIndex + viewRows;
      index++
    ) {
      console.log("Processing row " + index);

      let row = rows[index];
      ret.push(this.getRow(row, rowIndex++));
    }

    return ret;
  };

  render() {
    let rows = this.getRows(data);

    return (
      <div ref="container" className="rows-container">
        <div ref="innerContainer" className="rows-inner-container">
          {rows}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DynamicGrid;
```

What am I getting as a result is the following:

```
HEIGHTS:
CONTAINER: 630 INNER CONTAINER: 17
STATE:
viewRows: 1 - viewAddRows: true
HEIGHTS:
CONTAINER: 630 INNER CONTAINER: 17
STATE:
viewRows: 2 - viewAddRows: true
HEIGHTS:
CONTAINER: 630 INNER CONTAINER: 17
STATE:
viewRows: 3 - viewAddRows: true
HEIGHTS:
CONTAINER: 630 INNER CONTAINER: 17
STATE:
viewRows: 4 - viewAddRows: true
...
```

From the log I can see that the `innerContainer` height is not being updated after `componentDidUpdate`, and that is an assumption I've made to build my algorithm.

So, how can I get the new height of `innerContainer` after a state update, so that I can fill my `container` with rows ?

If this behaviour is not possible, how I can solve the problem of the dynamic height rows ?

Comment: You have your rows varibale set to a static variable `let rows = "RENATO"` right now so you are just adding that one thing at a height of 17.  Uncomment your `let rows = getRows()` function in your render and it seems to be working for me before i get a Maximum update depth exceeded warning

Comment: I don't think you can call setState inside componenDidUpdate, or will get an infinite loop. Maybe thats what the warning is about

Comment: Corrected @Steve K

Comment: @Mendes So are you seeing the new heights being applied now? Because I am getting the correct heights up until the point where a Maximum update depth exceeded warning which is because you are setting the state repeatedly too many times in your function.